# How to find name of my XAML file in my WPF application at run time

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on very complex WPF application which has many resource files because of which XAML doesn't load at design time. I want to find names of XAML files, at run time. I am trying to use snoop but not able to find name of XAML file. Please help

Comment: Why do you want to have the XAML file name? What do you want to achieve? Perhaps WPF inspector can help, have you tried it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say Xaml does not load at design time?

Comment: XAML not loading in the designer can have many reasons. As far as I understand you, you want to see where the different parts of your UI are defined, right?

Comment: I mean to say that designer doesn't load at design time. It always gives resource file error (its normal as resource file exists in other project). I need to make a change in a XAML of screen and if I dont know what is name of that view and where it is in the project, how can I find its XAML to make changes????

Comment: Okay, seems that I understood you correctly. Can you provide some metrics? How many XAML files are in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do this by starting at a high level of the UI (for example MainWindow) 
and the draw the components on paper that I find there, especially the grids.

Then I try to figure out where the elements of my application are in that view.

If you have multiple views, this can be somewhat timeconsuming. But if you
cannot just click through the designer windows, this is one of the fastest
possible ways to do it.

Okay, if you only have minor changes, you can try to find the element that
you want to change by using string search.

Find the label you want, if it is a resource string, find the usage of it.

If you have a complex MVVM application, you can start by investigating
the ViewModels used. They can be a better starting point than the View
itself.

-edit-
WPF Inspector can give you good hints on where to search.
You can get it here: [WPF Inspector home](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Using Snoop won't give you file names but you should be able to locate some type names (i.e. UserControls, custom controls, etc) or elements with x:Names by looking through the visual tree view near where you're trying to get to after using the Ctrl-Shift mouse-over shortcut. Searching for either usages of types (in the case of controls) or using Find in Files on all solution *.xaml files should help you find the elements you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for it for your own needs, you can call BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(v) on any visual and it will give you the Uri of the resource that your visual comes from. From this Uri you can get the origin xaml file